# Show nav on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

On large screens I have a side-nav that is looking just good. But on smaller screens (let's say less than 768px) I want the nav to have a width of 46px (showing only the icons). And when I mouse-hover on the icons I want the nav to be showed as in large screens.

```
<!-- https://codepen.io/JFarrow/pen/fFrpg -->
```

On the codepen you can see a working example achieved by CSS

Can I achieve the same thing using Javascript/jQuery?

```css
.navbar-sidenav {
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">


<ul class="nav navbar-sidenav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link nav-link-p" href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt margin-r"></i> Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link nav-link-p" href="users.html"><i class="fas fa-users margin-r"></i> Users</a>
    </li>
    
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link nav-link-p" href="fatura.html"><i class="fas fa-euro-sign margin-r"></i> Fatura</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why would you want to achieve the same with javascript or jQuery if you already have it in CSS??

Comment: @caramba I haven't made that with CSS, and on mobile there are some problems showing sometimes.

Comment: just adapt the css of the pen to cater for your larger screen... no need for js

Comment: If there are problems fix those problems. Adding more technology to problems is bad! Obviously there are reasons where you need to use javascript, but its hard to write good and clean javascript if it has to fix problems generated in CSS (which could and should be fixed in CSS at first!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
if($(window).width() < 768){
    $(document).find('.navbar-sidenav').css('width', ' 46px')
        $(document).find('.big').hide();
        $(document).on('mouseover', '.navbar-sidenav', function(){
            $(document).find('.big').show();
            $(document).find('.small').hide();
            $(document).find('.navbar-sidenav').css('width', '200px')
        })

    $(document).on('mouseout', '.navbar-sidenav', function(){
        $(document).find('.navbar-sidenav').css('width', ' 46px')
        $(document).find('.big').hide();
        $(document).find('.small').show();
    })
 }else{
    $(document).find('.small').hide();
 }
```

```css
.navbar-sidenav {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 75px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 28px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="nav navbar-sidenav">
    <li class="nav-item big">
        <a class="nav-link nav-link-p" href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt margin-r"></i> Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    
    <li class="nav-item small">
        <a class="nav-link nav-link-p" href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt margin-r"></i></a>
    </li>
    
    <li class="nav-item big">
        <a class="nav-link nav-link-p" href="users.html"><i class="fas fa-users margin-r"></i> Users</a>
    </li>
    
    <li class="nav-item small">
        <a class="nav-link nav-link-p" href="users.html"><i class="fas fa-users margin-r"></i></a>
    </li>
    
    <li class="nav-item big">
        <a class="nav-link nav-link-p" href="fatura.html"><i class="fas fa-euro-sign margin-r"></i> Fatura</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item small">
        <a class="nav-link nav-link-p" href="fatura.html"><i class="fas fa-euro-sign margin-r"></i></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: as I stated already in the above comment. It's bad to use technology if not needed. I don't like this answer because you add HTML which is not needed. Actually you just need to change the style and that for you can only use CSS, as simple as that.

Comment: @caramba OP asked for a JavaScript / jQuery method, they stated that they already knew how to achieve the outcome with CSS

Comment: @caramba i was answering to **Can I achieve the same thing using Javascript/jQuery?** which was asked...i do not know which question you are answering

Comment: [See this comment where he says: "@caramba I haven't made that with CSS, and on mobile there are some problems showing sometimes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57008049/show-nav-on-mouse-hover?noredirect=1#comment100549036_57008049) <= so CSS problems, can be solved with CSS. That's why I answered

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the hover property in css and then just changing the original element's opacity to 0. You can then obviously add a transition "fade" to it to make it look smoother.

Answer (score 0):

CSS only solution ([here you can resize the screen and it changes it accordingly](https://jsfiddle.net/3nsd76j9/))

```css
.navbar-sidenav {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 75px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 28px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* only applies is screen size is less then 768px wide */
@media (max-width: 768px) {

    .navbar-sidenav {
        width: 46px;
    }

    .navbar-sidenav .nav-link > span {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .navbar-sidenav:hover {
        width: 200px;
    }
    
    .navbar-sidenav:hover .nav-link > span {
        display: inline-block;
    }
  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="nav navbar-sidenav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link nav-link-p" href="index.html">
            <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt margin-r"></i>
            <span>Dashboard</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link nav-link-p" href="users.html">
            <i class="fas fa-users margin-r"></i>
            <span>Users</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link nav-link-p" href="fatura.html">
            <i class="fas fa-euro-sign margin-r"></i>
            <span>Fatura</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

you can also do animations (sliding in from the left) with CSS only, see the next snippet

```css
.navbar-sidenav {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 75px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 28px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* only applies is screen size is less then 768px wide */
@media (max-width: 768px) {

    .navbar-sidenav {
        width: 46px;
        
        -webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
           -moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
             -o-transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
                transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .nav-link {
        position: relative;
    }

    .navbar-sidenav .nav-link > span {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        left: -200px;
        top: 10px;
        visibility: hidden;
        
        -webkit-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
           -moz-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
             -o-transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
                transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .navbar-sidenav:hover {
        width: 200px;
    }
    
    .navbar-sidenav:hover .nav-link > span {
        visibility: visible;
        left: 50px;
    }
  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="nav navbar-sidenav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link nav-link-p" href="index.html">
            <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt margin-r"></i>
            <span>Dashboard</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link nav-link-p" href="users.html">
            <i class="fas fa-users margin-r"></i>
            <span>Users</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link nav-link-p" href="fatura.html">
            <i class="fas fa-euro-sign margin-r"></i>
            <span>Fatura</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```